# Send string as arguments in bash

Tags: bash

I have a string:

```
arguments="2 3 4"
```

And I want to send those arguments to a file file.py e.g.,

```
python file.py 2 3 4
```

How would I do that only using the string? The snippet below doesn't work (it just sends one argument, the entire string itself..).

```
python file.py $arguments ?
```

Comment: Are you sure your shell isn't zsh? That code should work exactly as given in bash (though it isn't good practice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash (as opposed to zsh), that code should work as-given. That said, you might try ensuring that IFS contains a space:

```
IFS=' '
```

or, to reset it to defaults:

```
unset IFS
```

...before running that string. `IFS` determines which characters are used in shell-splitting, so if it doesn't contain a space, arguments separated by spaces won't be expanded.

---

Alternately -- preferably -- use an array:

```
arguments=( 2 3 4 )
python file.py "${arguments[@]}"
```

In that format, you can use arguments containing spaces:

```
arguments=(2 "thirty three" 4 )
```

...which will not work otherwise, for reasons documented in [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Unsetting `IFS` does not reset it to its default (which is `<space><tab>< newline >`), but does cause words to be split on spaces only.

Comment: @chepner, on doing a quick test (running `unset IFS` and expanding a variable with tab-delimited values), I'm getting behavior consistent with the `$' \t\n'` default being in use. I'm using 4.3.18(1)-release.

Comment: OK, I have too many versions of `bash` installed on my laptop. Looks like the shell's behavior when `IFS` is unset changed sometime between 3.2 and 4.1 (probably 4.0? the change log doesn't seem to acknowledge it).

Answer (score 1):

Better to use BASH arrays:

```
arguments=(2 3 4)
python file.py "${arguments[@]}"
```